# Pass a dropdown selected value from one screen to another screen new form dropdown in PowerApps

Tags: powerapps, powerapps-formula, powerapps-selected-items

I have a dropdown (Dropdown1) in screen1. I need to pass the selected dropdown value of DropDown1 to screen2 which has a new form. The new form already has the dropdown (Dropdown2) from the SharePoint list. I want to populate the newform dropdown with the Dropdown1.Selected.Value. Is this possible? Also I have a lookup column which takes the value from Dropdown2.

I tried setting up a variable which selects the dropdown1 value on navigating to new form screen. I tried changing the Default of the dropdown to the variable and it throws me an error. I updated the entire datacard to the variable which still didnt help

Comment: Are those both drop downs have same data source? both are drop downs or combo boxes? Try settings `Default` property of Dropdown2 to `Dropdown1.Selected.Value` directly. let me know if it works.